# Should I have Multiple Content Types for Projects

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I plan on storing project documents such as Scope docs, Business Requirement docs, Technical Design Docs, Status Update docs, etc. Would I create a Project Parent Content Type, and then have child content types for the docs I mention above.

Alternative would I just have 1 Content Type called projects and create a site column called Project Document Type.  Note I would not anticpate I would ever create a new document for these content type(s), I would only be uploading docs to these content types.

I have read that you should not create too many content types which I understand, but I also want to balance out the searchability factor with the usability factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on what the project is and what you are creating. Use them where they make sense. If the scope of your project is creating a document library that could be provisioned on any site, then using a content type to be able to roll all that data up makes sense. If you are creating singular one off things, then no, just apply columns to your list library. There are other ways to get at the data besides content types if you need to surface it.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider doing this for a variety of reasons, search being one of them. This would also allow you to do things like have different metadata fields for different document type, retention schedules etc...

Comment: Hi Chris...just to clarify you are indicating to create multiple content types

Comment: Where it makes sense yes. You can inherit from a common root CT if you feel they are related somehow too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using content types since you're specifying document types in your question.

- Managing general columns in your parent content type, child content types inherit the general columns.
- Allows you to add specific columns to your child content types, creating unique content types for your project documents.
- Add new or change columns easily to your content types.
- Further refine your search queries to certain project documents based on a content type. Additional columns allow you to refine your search query even further.
- Set a retention policy for a content type.

Just the tip of the iceberg when using content types instead of a column to specify the document type.

Comment: I guess my struggle is I want to minimize the Content Types a user will select from...If I have 40 Content Types for a subsite it may get ugly in terms of users being overwhelmed with what content type to select.